# How to get a jQuery plugin to still identify an element after it was added to the DOM through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dom

OK, so I am having some trouble getting my head round a solution to get a certain jQuery plugin to work after an AJAX call has been successful and placed the data into the DOM.

The plugin is jScroll and I am sure that this plugin only identifies the element call upon on page load, so if the element is loaded into the DOM through the AJAX call the plugin will not recognise the it thus not working.

I sthere any way round this that does not require a re-writing of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do something like -

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  $('.result').jscroll()
});
```

Which would get the result from the server add it to an element, then set up the jScroll functionality on that element.

Comment: Good thinking Batman :) Just tried that and it works albeit me needing to tweak the CSS for that element to get it positioned correctly. Thank you very much.